# Facebook - How to open new tab in fan page without create a new application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

How can I create a new tabs in facebook page without create a new application `iframe`?
I want to use my application and just pass a parameters that will control the content.

Is it possible or do I have to open 1 application in 1 tab?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each "tab" represent an application. So you need a **new** application for each **new** tab.